# Como calcular número de soluções de um puzzle usando recursão

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Como um trabalho preciso desenvolver um algorítimo que calcula a quantidade de respostas possíveis para um puzzle, o jogo consiste em um arranjo de n peças pretas/brancas, quando uma peça é removida as adjacentes trocam de cor, só se pode remover peças pretas e o objetivo é remover todas as peças. Após algumas horas olhando para o código não consigo enxergar o erro, o algoritmo está seguindo apenas 1 caminho e na volta das recursões aparentemente ele não continua a iteração `for`. A resposta pro exemplo contido no código deveria ser 11, está retornando 1.

```
finished = 0

def jogovira(lista, n):
    global finished
    if (solucionado(lista, n)):
        finished += 1
        print("solucao encontrada!")
        return
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            if lista[i] == 'p':
                novalista = tira(lista, i, n)
                jogovira(novalista, n)
        return


def solucionado(l, n):
    for f in range(n):
        if (l[f] != 'x'):
            return False
    return True

def tira(l, j, n):
    m = l
    m[j] = 'x'
    if (j<n-1):
        m[j+1] = troca(l, j+1)
    if (j>0):
          m[j-1] = troca(l, j-1)
    return m

def troca(v, k):
    if (v[k] == 'x'):
        return 'x'
    if (v[k] == 'p'):
        return 'b'
    if (v[k] == 'b'):
        return 'p'


jogovira(['b', 'p', 'b', 'p', 'p'], 5)
print(finished)
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o algorítmico, há um link por aí com a descrição?

Comment: esse link que explica o problema:
http://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/programacao/nivel2/2011f2p2_vira

a função jogovira é a função principal que tentara fazer todos os caminhos possiveis recursivamente, a função solucionado testa se chegou em uma resposta, a função tira remove um peça e chama a função troca que inverte as peças adjacentes.

Debugando um pouco o codigo, vi que o problema se encontra na recursão, quando ele volta da recursão após chegar na solução, ele tenta usar a lista solucionada pra achar as outras respostas, ao invez de usar a lista em que a recursão atual estava.

Comment: Então eu presumo que você você já solucionou seu problema. Que tal postar sua resposta e marcá-la como resposta certa? Isso  é possível aqui no SO.